# Django CMS losing data from draft to live

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-cms

I'm creating a carousel plugin using the filer plugin to access easily images.
The carousel is simply made with Bootstrap Carousel.

The problem is that my carousel is displayed properly in draft but when I pass to live, only the arrow are remaining.

When I try to debug with some "hello" in the template this file :

```
      {% load thumbnail %}

    <div id="myCarousel" class="gallery carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="CMSBcarouselPlugin_{{ gallery.pk }}">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {% for image in images %}  
    {% if forloop.first %}
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">  </li>
    {% else %}
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="{forloop.counter}"></li>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ol>

etc.
```

I can figure only "hello" outside the for loop are display.

I don't understand why it is not working in live when it works in draft.

Her is my simple cms_plugin.py file :

```
class BcarouselPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
  model = Bcarousel
  name = _("Bcarousel")
  render_template = "bcarousel_plugin/bcarousel_plugin.html"
  raw_id_fields = ('image',)

  fields = ['title', 'template' ]

  def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
    context['images'] = instance.image_set.all()
    context['gallery'] = instance
    try:
        loader.get_template('bcarousel_plugin/' + instance.template)
        self.render_template = 'bcarousel_plugin/' + instance.template
    except:
        pass
    return context

  def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    form=super(BcarouselPlugin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
    form.base_fields['template'] = forms.ChoiceField(
        choices=self._get_available_templates(),
        required=False
    )
    return form

  def _get_available_templates(self):
    choices = (('default', _('Bcarousel-Default')),)
    try:
        choices += settings.BCAROUSEL_PLUGIN_TEMPLATES
    except:
        pass
    return choices

plugin_pool.register_plugin(BcarouselPlugin)
```

If someone got an idea, it would be priceless.

I thank you in advance

Comment: If you can post your two models i could update the sample code and make sure it is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a copy_relationships method within your plugin model.

When publishing you are literally duplicating the model row. You need to tell the related model how to copy its records and associate them to the correct instance. The CMS allows you to define a method **copy_relations** which you need to implement.

```
def copy_relations(self, oldinstance):
    for image in oldinstance.image_set.all():
        image.pk = None
        image.plugin = self
        image.save()
```

[Documentation](https://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/support-3.0.x/how_to/custom_plugins.html?highlight=copy_relations#handling-relations)

Comment: Yeah, I checked this way, but it doesn't work :( I added it in the bcarousel model class but...

Comment: Oh, you were right, I just did it the wrong way. Thank you very much man !